# How to set visibility between two layouts

Tags: android

Here is the XML code for 2 layouts I need to set the visibility of your cart is empty and shop now button when the length of the list is 0.  otherwise I should show only RecyclerView. I have written code in fragment but when we load our fragment and size of list is not zero then also it is showing your cart is empty and shop now button for fraction of seconds after that Recycler view is loading... but I want to show this empty text and Shop now button only when there is nothing in our cart.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.brinhitamobile.krishigaadi.CartFragment"
android:weightSum="1">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="490dp" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearEmpty"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="your cart is empty"
        android:textAlignment="center"
       android:visibility="gone"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"

        android:id="@+id/tvEmpty" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonShop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:background="#32cd32"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="SHOP NOW"

        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="485dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/texttotPrice"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text=" "
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"

                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonChck"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:text="checkout"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

here is my java code
public class CartFragment extends Fragment
{

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
Button checkout,shopnow;
ArrayList<Cart> list;
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
MyAdapter myAdapter;
Mytask mytask;
TextView textViewTotalPrice,tv100;
public boolean checkinternet()
{
    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (info != null && info.isConnected() == true) {
        return true;

    }
    return false;
}
public CartFragment() {
  }

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    myAdapter.grandTotal(list);
    Log.d("price","Onstart" );

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cart, container, false);
    checkout = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonChck);
    tv100= (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvEmpty);
    textViewTotalPrice = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.texttotPrice);
    shopnow = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonShop);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler1);
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,
            false);
    myAdapter = new MyAdapter();

    list = new ArrayList<Cart>();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter); //adapter --to--> recyclerview
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager); //recyclerview--to--> layoutmanager

    if (myAdapter.getItemCount()==0) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"emptycart",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("size", "onCreateView2: "+list.size());
        tv100.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        checkout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textViewTotalPrice.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        shopnow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if (checkinternet() == true) {
        mytask = new Mytask();
        String AddedBy = "gaurav";

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "no internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    Double x = Store.grandPrice.getGrandprice();
    Log.d("Price","totalprice"+x);
    checkout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {            }
    });
    shopnow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return v;
}
public class Mytask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    URL myurl;
    HttpURLConnection con;
    InputStream is;
    InputStreamReader reader;
    BufferedReader br;
    String s = null;
    StringBuilder sb;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        try {
            myurl = new URL(strings[0]);
            con = (HttpURLConnection) myurl.openConnection();
            is = con.getInputStream();
            reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
            br = new BufferedReader(reader);
            sb = new StringBuilder();

            do {
                s = br.readLine();
                sb.append(s);

            } while (s != null);
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("b37", "doInBackground: malform " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("b37", "doInBackground: io exception " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s)
    {

        try {
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(s);
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject j = array.getJSONObject(i);
                String cartid = j.getString("CartId");
                String productid = j.getString("ProductId");
                String image1 = j.getString("ProductImagePath");
                String title = j.getString("ProductName");
                //     String subtitle = j.getString("subtitle");
                String price = j.getString("Price");
                String description = j.getString("ProductDescription");
                String quantity = j.getString("Quantity");
                String shippingcharges = j.getString("ShippingCharges");
                String discount = j.getString("Discount");
                String totalprice = j.getString("TotalPrice");
                Cart r = new Cart(productid, image1, title, price, description, cartid, quantity, shippingcharges, discount, totalprice);
                list.add(r);
                cart.setProductid(productid);
                cart.setImage1(image1);
                cart.setTitle(title);
                cart.setPrice(price);
                cart.setDescription(description);
                cart.setCartid(cartid);
                cart.setQuantity(quantity);
                cart.setShippingcharges(shippingcharges);
                cart.setDiscount(discount);
                cart.setTotalprice(totalprice);

                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            if (s != null) {

            }

        } catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartFragment.MyAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
    @Override
    public CartFragment.MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cart, parent, false);
        CartFragment.MyAdapter.ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Cart k = list.get(position);
        holder.tv1.setText(k.getTitle());
        holder.tv2.setText(k.getDescription());
        holder.tv3.setText("Rs" + Double.parseDouble(k.getPrice()));
        holder.tv4.setText(k.getQuantity());
        holder.tv5.setText(k.getDiscount() + "% off");
        holder.tv7.setText("RS " + k.getTotalprice());
        String imagepath = k.getImage1();
        Glide.with(CartFragment.this).load(imagepath).into(holder.iv1);      
        grandTotal(list);        
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return list.size();
    }
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView tv1, tv2, tv3, tv4, tv5, tv7;
        public ImageView iv1, iv2, iv3;
        public Button b1, b2;
        public ImageButton ib1, ib2
```

public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

```
            super(itemView);

            tv1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            tv7 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTotalPrice);
            tv2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSubtitle);
            tv3 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
            tv3.setPaintFlags(tv3.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            tv4 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvQty);
itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvShippingCharge);
            ib1 = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.qty_decrease);
            ib2 = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.qty_increase);
            b1 = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnRemove);
            b2 = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnWishList);
            iv2 = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageDelete);
            iv3 = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageWish);
            iv1 = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);//FOR DISPLAYING ACTOR NAME

            b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                    Cart selectedItem = list.get(pos);
                    String removeCartid = selectedItem.getCartid();         
                    Store.deletecartitem.setDeletecartid(removeCartid);
                    list.remove(selectedItem.getCartid());
                    MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter();                       
                    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    ft.detach(CartFragment.this).attach(CartFragment.this).commit();

                    Toast.makeText(CartFragment.this.getActivity(), " Item Removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    new Deletetask().execute();

                }
            });


            ib2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


                    new Updatequantity().execute();
                }
            });

            ib1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String _stringVal;
                    int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                    String quantity = tv4.getText().toString();
                    final Cart selectedItem = list.get(pos);
                    final String productprice = selectedItem.getPrice();
                    final double productpriced = Double.parseDouble(productprice);
                    String productid = selectedItem.getProductid();
                    Store.updatequantityprameter.setPid(productid);
                    String productname = selectedItem.getTitle();
                    Store.updatequantityprameter.setPname(productname);                       
                    int j = Integer.parseInt(quantity);
                    Log.d("src", "Decreasing value...");
                    if (j > 1) {                           
                        _stringVal = String.valueOf(j);
                        tv4.setText(_stringVal);

                        double subtotalprice = --j * productpriced * (1 / ((double) (j + 1)));
                        Store.updatequantityprameter.setPprice(String.valueOf(subtotalprice));
                        Store.updatequantityprameter.setPquantity(String.valueOf(j));
                    } else
                        {
                        double subtotalprice = j * productpriced;
                        Store.updatequantityprameter.setPprice(String.valueOf(subtotalprice));
                    }

                    String imagepath = selectedItem.getImage1();
                    Store.updatequantityprameter.setPimagepath(imagepath);
                    String productdescription = selectedItem.getDescription();
                    Store.updatequantityprameter.setPdescription(productdescription);
                    String productshippingcharges = selectedItem.getShippingcharges();
                    Store.updatequantityprameter.setPshippingcharge(productshippingcharges);
                    String productdiscount = selectedItem.getDiscount();
                    Store.updatequantityprameter.setPdiscount(productdiscount);
                    String producttotalprice = selectedItem.getTotalprice();
                    Store.updatequantityprameter.setPtotalprice(producttotalprice);
                    MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter();
                    recyclerView.refreshDrawableState();
                    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    ft.detach(CartFragment.this).attach(CartFragment.this).commit();
                    new Updatequantity().execute();
                }});
            if (myAdapter.getItemCount()!=0) {
                Log.d("size", "onCreateView1: "+list.size());
                tv100.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                checkout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textViewTotalPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                shopnow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }}}

    private void grandTotal(ArrayList<Cart> list) {
        int tPrice = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            String x = list.get(i).getPrice();
            double xr = Double.parseDouble(x);
            tPrice += xr;
            Store.grandPrice.setGrandprice(Double.valueOf(tPrice));
            Log.d("Price", "pric" + Store.grandPrice.getGrandprice());
            textViewTotalPrice.setText("Total Rs "+Store.grandPrice.getGrandprice());
            }}}}
```

Comment: You question is a little bit confusing. Can you edit trying to explain better what you need? A good tip would be you put only the first thing that you need to do, not everything and go step-by-step

Comment: Set the button to `Invisible` Or `Gone` as per your need in xml. This will make the button disappear when your page loads. If your `list` appears to be not empty , then set the visibility to button to `Visible`  in your code.

Comment: @Canato i have designed frame Layout in that frame Layout i have used one text view and and one button and again in inner framelayout i have used recyclerview when i remove the recycler item particularly i am seeing that TextView and shop NOw as shown in Xml file for fraction of second .but i want to see that button after removing all the recycler view items i.e. size is 0 also i am posting java code.

Comment: @Jimmy Hi i am posting my java code just advice wher i have to write code for visiblity in my fragment.

Comment: you have this line `shopnow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` when count==0  ( in `onCreateView` method ). Add an `else` statement for that if and move that line to the else statement. Also you need to do this same whereever you are in need of calling `notifydatasetchanged` on adapter. You have to hide if size is 0,else show.

Comment: @Jimmy not working please see my requirements once again i have edited and please let me know ..Thanks in advance

Comment: @GauravSingh In onCreate method, your `if(myAdapter.getItemCount()==0) ` seems to be executed every time as your adapter is empty. So your two views are visible when the activity loads regardless of visibility settings in layout xml. You need to make those two fields `gone` or `invisible` all the time and make them `visible` explicitly when there are contents in cart list,else make them invisible explicitly by adding `else`.So,from any place your list gets updated, check if it is empty. If yes, set visibility to gone, else set visible. If still fails, debug and find which 'visible` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the cart is empty then make your views invisible using [setVisibility()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int))

Answer (score 0):

you can use in xml **android:visibility="gone"** to hide layout or button
in activity or fragment **layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);** for hide or **layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);** for visible , just make your logic for list count